# Android: Achieve the content inside the linear layout through Java

Tags: java, android

I have a sample content.xml whose textview is hard coded right now. But application requirement is such these these have to populated according to the results fetched from db. Suppose I have a service which return list of string which needs to populated as text in text view how can this be achieved in Java Code?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 4"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 6"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Content 7"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can programatically add views to a layout using the ".addView()" method. Create a new TextView with the proper parameters and add it to your layout.

Comment: Why not using a `ListView` ?

Comment: can you please provide a sample code example?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a ListView as all your items seem to be arranged in a vertical LinearLayout. Then it's a matter of defining an ArrayAdapter, row layout xml and filling the adapter with results from your database query.

Comment: can you please provide me a sample code as I am very new to Android Development